# How to add a different title to LTIview?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot step response of a second order transfer function using LTIview in different conditions such as underdamped,critically damped condition etc. I want to plot them in the same matlab program so want to give my own title names such as 'underdamped' condition. But the following code for plot function doesn't work and the GUI gives the preinitialised names

```
figure,ltiview('step',trf),title('underdmp')
```

Or

```
ltiview('step',trf),title('overdamped')
```

How to solve this problem?  And give the names according to my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to costomize the title property of a plot in a standard toolbox window, you need to retrieve the axes object of the figure.

The following code uses lti examples to show the solution:

```
load ltiexamples;
H = ltiview(sys_dc);
obj = findobj(H, 'type', 'axes');
title(obj, 'my name here');
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**EDIT**

A Bode plot consists of two plots and respectively of two axes-objects. So you need to put an object index to access the axes object.

```
load ltiexamples;
H = ltiview('bode', sys_dc);
obj = findobj(H, 'type', 'axes');
title(obj(1), 'Custom title for the bode plot');
```

[image]

Comment: Hello I have written, h = ltiview('bode',trf) ; object = findobj(h,'type','axes'); title(obj, 'my plot'); it doesn't run. It gives an error incorrect number of input arguments of title. Could you help me further?

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? I'm using R2015a

Comment: Mine is R2013a. What's the other way then?  Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you use the data from the example which I used? Maybe it depends upon..

Comment: Yup it works. Even if I replace 'bode' with 'step', it works. But it doesn't give the same result for bode. Anyway thanks I am accepting your answer as it works for step. Thank you :) if you find a reason or code that can run for bode also please edit the answer with that.

Comment: Perfect, at least we found some bad examples. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Great. I think as bode gives both magnitude and phase plot together there's some problem when the picture breaks in two halves of different mag plot and phase plot. Will wait for your answer. Meanwhile I will try too. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the answer by adding a case of a Bode plot. You have to specify an object index to access the axes.