# Matlab Bode Plot Title Customisation - Turning Off Title and Input/Output

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

For the Bode plot below, I am trying to remove the title and the input/output line:

[image: Sample Bode Plot]

I have found methods to null the title line, but these do not 'collapse' it - which would make it pointless as my reason for removing the title is conserving the space it takes.

I also want to get entirely rid of the line detailing the input and output but I have not even managed to edit the contents there.

I have investigated the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034776/how-to-add-a-different-title-to-ltiview/34043489#34043489) and the Matlab help files for [bode](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bode.html), [bodeplot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bodeplot.html) and [bodeoptions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bodeoptions.html).

What would be the appropriate code solution for achieving this?

For a MWE, try the below but as this applies generally, I am not sure this is useful for this question:

```
bode(tf([10000 0],[1 2.5 1.15]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the gain and phase vectors and plot them out seperately with whatever title and x/y labels you would like:

```
[mag,phase,wout] = bode(tf([10000 0],[1 2.5 1.15]))
```

Here is an example of how to get a similar plot without a title:

```
% Plot 
% Old way
bode(tf([10000 0],[1 2.5 1.15]))

% new way
figure(2)
[mag,phase,wout] = bode(tf([10000 0],[1 2.5 1.15]))
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1) % gain plot
    plot(wout, 20*log10(mag(:)))
    set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')
    ylabel('Magnitude (dB)')
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2) % Phase plot 
    plot(wout, phase(:))
    set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')
    xlabel('Frequency (rad/s)')
    ylabel('Phase (deg)')
```

Comment: Admittedly this solves the asked question, or, is at the very least, a workaround to the problem. I've hence accepted the answer, but I'll note that I didn't end up changing the Bode plots in my own work for this project as I thought this approach resulted in extra work. Admittedly I could have devised a method for an automatic using this here, but I didn't get that far.

Comment: Hey gktscrk, take a look at a better working example above. It makes nearly an exact duplicate of the bode plot without the title. Hope this helps!