# how do you add a title to an ltiview?

Tags: matlab

so i have this code:

```
ltiview({'step';'impulse';'bode';'pzmap'}, sys);
```

which opens up my lti system analyzer and gives me all my graphs [image: as such]

how do i go about adding a title to the entire thing, all together?

i have tried doing

```
ltiview({'step';'impulse';'bode';'pzmap'}, sys);
title('system number 1');
```

but it doesnt work, it just creates a new empty graph and gives it that title. is there anyway to fix this? thank you

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034776/how-to-add-a-different-title-to-ltiview)

Comment: thats talking about changing the title of individual plots, i want to add a super title to all of the plots.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the puzzle...

The reason you can't set the main title is because there are **hidden** handles.
I am not sure the solution is consistent among different versions of MATLAB (I am using R2109a Windows version).
I suggest two solutions, I hope at least one works for you.

- Show Hidden Handles:
  Execute `set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on');` for showing all hidden handles.

Example:

```
sys1 = rss(3,2,2);
sys2 = rss(4,2,2);
h = ltiview(sys1,'r-*',sys2,'m--');

set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on');

obj = findobj(h, 'Type', 'Axes');
title(obj(1), 'My Title');
```

Result:
[image]

---

- Add new axes (object) to the top of the figure, and add text to the axes:

Example:

```
sys1 = rss(3,2,2);
sys2 = rss(4,2,2);
h = ltiview(sys1,'r-*',sys2,'m--');

set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on');

obj = findobj(h, 'Type', 'Axes');
%title(obj(1), 'My Title');

title(obj(1), []);
ax = axes('Parent', h, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.5-0.2/2, 0.92, 0.2, 0.1], 'Color', get(h, 'Color'), 'XColor', 'none', 'YColor', 'none');
text(ax, 0.5, 0.5, 'My Title', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'FontSize', 14);
```

Result:
[image]